# Match first address using regular expressions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I've got pretty dirty data of client addresses. For each client, there are 2 or more addresses in one string. Using regular expressions in Oracle I want to subtract the first one.

It would be very easy if there was the same separator as `';'`. But sometimes there is a comma. And comma is also used within an address to separate city, street, and building.

I've got Russian addresses so I translated them for you.

For example, I have a string with multiple addresses:

[image]

A comma is a separator, but it also separates blocks inside addresses.
So I could match the first address by matching everything until the second `'\sul\.'`.

But I don't how to do it. `Regexp_substr(address, '.*,\sul')`  will return

[image]

This is far from what I need.

So how can I subtract everything until second `,\sul\.` ?

`Russia, Moscow, ul. Tverskaya, d.32` should be returned.

Comment: `,\sul` would not help since `ul.` is part of the first address you want to extract. Unless you can describe the start/end context of the expected matches there is no solution.

Comment: What is the result that you expect?

Comment: I expect Russia, Moscow, ul. Tverskaya, d.32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could address this requirement using `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` instead of regexes. The following expression should give you what you need:

```
SUBSTR(v, 1, INSTR(v, ', ul.', 1, 2) - 1)
```

`INSTR()` finds the position of the second occurence of string `', ul.'` in the source string, and `SUBSTR()` selects everything from the beginning of the string until that position (minus 1).

Example:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 'Russia, Moscow, ul. Tverskaya, d.32, ul. Yakimanka, d21, ul. Kalinina, d.43' address FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SUBSTR(address, 1, INSTR(address, ', ul.', 1, 2) - 1) adress1 FROM t
```

```
| ADRESS1                             |
| :---------------------------------- |
| Russia, Moscow, ul. Tverskaya, d.32 |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2af6d2c82cffb98f5bdb7988b8076f49)**

---

NB: this works as long as there are indeed at least two occurences of the given pattern in the string. If you happen to have values that do not match this spec and that you want to preserve, you would need an additional level of testing, like:

```
CASE INSTR(address, ', ul.', 1, 2)
    WHEN 0 THEN address
    ELSE SUBSTR(address, 1, INSTR(address, ', ul.', 1, 2) - 1) 
END adress1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a2864b5a6cea77e832bc6bec97090bdd)**

Comment: Thank you! It helps in most cases. And I will definitely use this solution. But regular expressions more flexible. For example, there are about 11 types of streets (avenue, embankment, highway, etc.) :) And I could use smth like regexp_substr(string, 'st|av|emb)

Comment: @РусланХ: I understand, however I doubt that your requirement can be properly adressed using regexps (also see the comment by Wiktor Stribiżew on your original question), so I went for regular string manip functions...